# Dashboard using ELatic Search and Kibana

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Can I  use  Elastic Search and Kibana  for  developing a dashboard  having  a mongodb database running on the server ?

What is the  pros and cons , if someone would help me with that ?

Thanks

Comment: You can do that. Pros and cons it's depend on your app

Comment: thanks for replying ....